# load page on button click in specific div area using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load a HTML file in `<div id="content"></div>` at button click using AJAX and jQuery but click is not loading it. Below is the code:

```
<body>    
<div id="header">    
<div id="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="navmenu1" name="radio"><label for="navmenu1">Home</label>
  <input type="radio" id="navmenu2" name="radio"><label for="navmenu2">Contact</label>
  <input type="radio" id="navmenu3" name="radio"><label for="navmenu3">Resume</label>
</div>
<div id="social">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/han.chang.10" target="new"><img src="img/facebook.png" class="facebook" alt="Facebook" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/han-chang/58/959/a74/"><img src="img/linkedin.png" class="linkedin" alt="linkedin" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/han-chang/58/959/a74/"><img src="img/twitter.png" class="twitter" alt="twitter" /></a>
    <a href="mailto:shuhanchang612@gmail.com"><img src="img/gmail.png" class="gmail" alt="gmail" /></a>
</div> 
</div><!--head-->

<div id="content-area">
    <div id="content"></div>    
</div>

<div id="footer-row">
   <footer>
      <div id="footer-row-1">
        <ul id="footer">
            <li>&copy 2013</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </footer>
</div> 
</body>
```

home.js as below:

```
$(function(){
    $("#radio").buttonset({
    $("#content").load("Page1.cshtml");
});
})
```

Comment: Looks to be an MVC view (extension .csthml) - which won't work...you need to load the page that uses the view itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues.

First, your jQuery is invalid. Why is `$("#content).load("Page1.csthml");` hanging out by itself in the middle of a javascript object?

Javascript objects, or at least ones that are passed as options, generally have this format:

```
{
    property1 : "value1",
    property2 : "value2
}
```

Your "object" has only a property or value, but not both. I think you're looking for this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#radio").buttonset();

    $("#radio").click(function() {
        $("#content).load("Page1.csthml");
    });
})
```

However, you have one more issue still: you can't call .cshtml files directly, you need to call a controller action that uses the .cshtml as it's view.

Comment: I see,  so I can load the html not cshtml, if I wanna load cshtml, I have to use controller action. thank you